# Loose coupling vs tight coupling of services

Tags: angular, loose-coupling, coupling

I understand that we at almost all times want to aim for loose coupling between components within an application & why.

But in the below example if someone could clarify as to why it isn't tightly coupled when we pass in a service as a parameter to a constructor so I could understand the logic that's going on under the hood.

```
export class Test(){

dataResults;

constructor(service: testService){

this.dataResults = service.getData()

}

}
```

Comment: you want to know its loose coupled or not

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're really asking about here. "Under the hood" is Angular's dependency injection system, which is a specific implementation not a broad architectural principle. You could argue that Test is still dependent on the TestService, but dependency inversion and constructor injection here means that you can swap out the service (e.g. for testing) which reduces the coupling, because Test doesn't create its own concrete TestService. You should probably read https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Tight coupling means** : Code written is dependent on one class only, for example if i write

```
service:TestService;
constructor(){
this.service = new TestService();
this.dataResults = service.getData()
}
```

above code is tightly coupled because if tomorrow if i want to replace `TestService` with `ActualService`, I have to open files which is consuming `TestService` and have to do modification.

Now, **Loose Coupling** is reverse of tight coupling , means class is not dependent directly on the class whose service it consuming. In higher order language like C# , for loose coupling code is written like this

```
public class A{
  A(IB service) {//here IB is interface , on which A class is depedant
   //use service here 
  }
}

public class B : IB { }
public class C : IB { }
```

so now A id dedpend on IB , you can easily do this

```
A a = new A(new B());
or 
A a = new A(new C());
```

so its create that A is depend on IB which can be B or C. so it becomes loosely coupled with B and C.

---

Now coming to your code which Angular code,

In angular when we make use of any service in out component , we do register it via provider either at module or at component.

```
[{ provide: Logger , useClass: Logger}]
```

and then in component it used like

```
constructor(service: Logger){
  this.dataResults = service.getData()
}
```

Now tomorrow if i want to replace Logger with BetterLooger I just need to do like this

```
[{ provide: Logger , useClass: BetterLogger}]
or 
[{ provide: Logger , useClass: TestLogger}]
```

with out going in component code , thats how it becomes loose coupled. Or even its very helpful in testing of components also, where one want to replace actul service with `MockService` (check here : https://angular.io/guide/testing)

for above to work `BetterLogger and TestLogger` must extend `Logger`. you can go there and check in detail : https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Further read : [Dependency Injection](https://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2014/01/dependency-injection-part-1.html) and [SOLID](https://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2015/07/solid-principle-in-detail.html)