# Retrieving a content projected inside a component into a variable

Tags: angular

I am trying to retrieve content projected by an angular component into a typescript variable.

I tried retrieving the content using @ViewChild decorator and display it using console log() but I get an error.

The following is the code I wrote in various files :

**app.component.html (Parent Component)**

```
<app-test>
    <div class="t1">
        Test Data 1
    </div>
    <div class="t2">
        Test Data 2
    </div>
</app-test>
```

**test.component.html (Child Component)**

```
 <div #tt>The following data was passed to this component:</div>
    <ng-content select=".t1" #t1></ng-content>
    <ng-content select=".t2" #t1></ng-content>
```

**test.component.ts (Child Component script)**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChildren, AfterContentInit, ElementRef } 
from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './test.component.scss' ]
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ViewChildren('t1') t1: ElementRef;
  @ViewChildren('t2') t2: ElementRef;
  @ViewChildren('tt') tt: ElementRef;
  constructor () { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
      console.log(this.t1.nativeElement.innerHTML);
      console.log(this.t2.nativeElement.innerHTML);
      console.log(this.tt.nativeElement.innerHTML);
  }

}
```

I get the following error running this code

> AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'nativeElement' of undefined
>       at TestComponent.push../src/app/test/test.component.ts.TestComponent.ngAfterContentInit
>   (test.component.ts:16)
>       at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:18847)
>       at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:18828)
>       at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:18818)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:19749)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:19986)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:19928)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:19751)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:20639)
>       at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:20317)

My question is how can I display following:

```
The following data was passed to this component:
 Test Data 1
 Test Data 2
```

in the console safely ?

Comment: I'm curious: why not declare the variable in a service, and then import that service where ever you need access to the variable? Services are great for sharing variables, so I'm thinking perhaps I've not understood your scenario.

Comment: @Bytech I am attempting create a reusable component which is independent of the application where it is put into use. Doesn't using services to transfer data (in this case) increase the coupling ?

Comment: In Angular, you can keep services loosely instead of tightly coupled. It sounds like in your case a Service is the way to go. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772612/loose-coupling-vs-tight-coupling-of-services/50772834#50772834 ... the second part of the post addresses Angular specifically. If this all fits as a solution to your problem, let me know and I'll put it into an official answer. If not, do let us know about the nuances that make Services a poor solution to your case.

Comment: @Bytech I have edited my question. The code under-neath app.component.html was not properly displayed because Stack Overflow actually rendered it.

Comment: @Bytech My question is really this: Is it possible in angular to retrieve the contents enclosed within the selector-tags of a child component into a variable in the child component.

Answer (score 4):

Use `@ContentChild()` instead of `@ViewChildren()`, here is the link where difference between these two decorators is explained pretty well: [What's the difference between @ViewChild and @ContentChild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326745/whats-the-difference-between-viewchild-and-contentchild)

Comment: Please provide a more thorough explanation of why the OP should use ContentChild instead of ViewChildren, as it may also be useful to other people searching for similar issues. No doubt doing so will also help raise your own reputation as being helpful to the community.

Comment: @Ako Javakhishvili Tried using @ContentChild() but I received a similar error.